# google map travel mode in iframe

Tags: google-maps

Its showing all possible mode, I want direction for only flying mode.
`(&mode=flying )` not working here, what is the solution?

```html
<iframe width=100% height=100% frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=delhi&ie=UTF8&output=embed&mode=flying" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details including more of your related code and solutions you have tried.  Check out [How to ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

replaced src url with : https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MY-KEY&origin=Current+Location&destination=delhi&mode=flying

Now its working fine